# Could large creatures pass through the narrow passage?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

The short question is:
**Can a large creature (such as a Troll or a Drider) pass through the narrow passage?**

The *official* answer is apparently a topic for debate (that I want to avoid).
For example, [this post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1586558/big-monsters-and-narrow-passageways) opens a can of worms and proposes houserules while [this short forum post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1003626/troll-and-narrow-passage) seems to briefly conclude that a troll can, in fact, pass through the narrow passage.

I'd normally just propose a ruling stating that trolls and driders are indeed able to pass through.
The odd thing is that [Errtu's card](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1083658/dungeons-dragons-legend-drizzt-board-game) specifically says:

> **Squeeze**: Errtu `can be placed over walls`, but the center square that this figure occupies must be open.

We don't have a similar clarification for trolls and driders.

Would the lack of such clarification imply that a large creature *can't* pass through a narrow passage?

Comment: I think the lack of clarification is more to do with the game line no longer being actively developed, than an actual decision about the ruling.

Comment: @KenHerbert So, perhaps [LoD](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/91872/dungeons-dragons-legend-drizzt-board-game) is the only game in the series with a narrow passage? If not, then I'm not sure if that's the case. According to [BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/9547/dungeons-and-dragons-adventure-system-board-games) the Temple of Elemental Evil Board Game was released only two years ago, and the Tomb of Annihilation Board Game will be released in just a couple months from now.

Comment: Well there you go. I didn't even know there was a 4th and 5th game in the series.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on https://rpg.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: @InbarRose the [tag:dnd-adventure-system] is a system for a series of board games. This Q is not about the Role Playing Game.